# Recover pods / dependencies?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Is there a way to recover a podFile or find out which dependencies you were using, if you had accidentally deleted the podfile?

Long story, but I don't have the podfile committed and compiling the project doesn't give me any hints of what dependencies I was using at all.

Help!

Comment: Do you have pods folder in your project?

Comment: You should use some form of source control in your projects for this exact reason. Even if you're only working on the project by yourself, or for a school project, creating a local Git repo and committing regularly will prevent issues like this.

Comment: i did commit to gitlab constantly...but I guess i didn't pay attention whether it was committing the podfile or not. :/  lesson learned.